# No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp, eclipse-pdt

I have upgraded eclipse 4.3 to eclipse 4.5. when I try to compile the same product with eclipse 4.5, I am getting a big list of errors.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

```
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.11.1.v20150805-0538
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.11.1.v20150805-0538
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.11.1.v20150806-0404
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.11.2.v20160128-0629
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation,1.5.100.v20141002-1241
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.9.1.v20160128-1343
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.8.0.v20150527-0946
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.11.2.v20151123-1510
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.1.200.v201404021757
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.400.v201403261418
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.core,1.2.0.v200908251833
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emf,1.2.400.v201505132009
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration,1.2.101.v201107081800
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.environment,1.0.400.v200912181831
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks,1.2.200.v201304241450
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.400.v201504292002
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.401.v201408132036
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030423
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.600.v201505072140
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.2.200.v201505132009
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.800.v201402172058
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.802.v201501312139
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.core,1.0.600.v201309182039
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.3.401.v201511181529
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation,1.0.600.v201505071819
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.601.v201512010225
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core,1.0.800.v201505130300
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.core,1.8.0.v201601132216
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.2.0.v201601132216
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.5.202.v201602111638
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.901.v201510130005
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation,1.2.700.v201508251749
 [java] [p2.director]  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.902.v201501211904
```

A problem occured while invoking the director.

I have seen few solutions online, but they the solution was more related to installing eclipse software from UI. My issue is more related to the build time.

I have taken vanilla eclipse, added necessary third party plugins and repositories. Any idea on what is the plugin/repository that is missing?

thanks!

Comment: Can someone please let me know the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurred while invoking the director then you should try the below solution.

Add this record tag above `<target name="runDirector" >`

`<record name="c:/users/pvyas/desktop/build.log" loglevel="verbose" append="false"/>`

in genericTargets.xml

`\\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_<supported-version>\scripts\genericTargets.xml`

This will generate logs and you will get the details about missing plugins. Once you will get the plugins then you can add those plugins to your dependency.